# Accompanying friend for a Canada visa?

Tags: visas, canada, standard-visitor-visas, family

We want to visit Canada on a short-term visitor visa for tourism. We are a family of 4 but we have a family friend traveling with us. While applying for the visa online and filling the questionnaire, it asks for additional family members traveling with me and their documents so shall I include our family friend in the same list? If not, how do we process it otherwise?

All 5 of us applied for a USA/UK visa in the same way in a single application. I just had to mention the people traveling with me, we applied as a group and went for interview together. We were granted the visa successfully.

Comment: How does a family friend legally metamorphose become a family member? Do you guys live in the same household? Methinks the fact that it was allowed by a US consular officer does not mean it is right or that another consular officer of a different country would view it the same.

Comment: No I'm just saying that the way other VISA Applications work including UK and USA is that they don't limit you to family members when it comes to "who is traveling with you". There can be group applications too. So maybe there is another way of doing it or are we out of options? @SheikPaulofOsawatomie

Comment: I think you can go ahead and add the person to the family application. You will not be refused a visa just because you added a family friend who you consider family. Worst case is you're told to file a separate application for the person concerned in which case you can file for said person as an individual with you as the sponsor/financier etc. It should not be a big deal and the support documents required will likely be the same with perhaps a letter of guardianship from parents required if said person is a minor and you're not the legal guardian..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canada does not offer a visa application form for a group, although you can submit those of your family in the same envelope, and you can reference your friend in your supporting documentation, but not as a family member.

> [Can I fill out one visa application for my whole family if we are travelling together](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=425&top=16)?
>
> No. Each person must complete and sign the Application for Temporary Resident Visa (IMM 5257), as well as any other forms needed. Each applicant aged 18 or over must also complete the Family Information form (IMM 5645).
>
> You can submit all family member applications in the same envelope with one payment receipt for the total fee for all of your applications.
>
> Parents or guardians can help children fill out their forms. Parents or guardians must sign the forms for any children under the age of 18.

Your friend, who plans to accompany your family on the visit, would need to apply separately, but provide the same itinerary, along with the [documents that support his/her application](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/pdf/kits/forms/IMM5484E.pdf). In particular, the explanation of the purpose of travel should include information about other with whom they'll travel (your family).

And, during any interviews, that you're all travelling together would be discussed, of course.